# Using multiple Style attributes inside react

Tags: reactjs

```
<div className="col-md-9">
           <span style={{color:this.props.todo.done ?'#e6e6e6' : '#4d4d4d'},
                        {textDecoration: this.props.todo.done ? '#e6e6e6 line-through' : 'none'}
                    }
           >
               {this.props.todo.value}
           </span>
</div>
```

I know the above one is wrong, but is there anyway to add multiple style attributes inside the span tag and make it work. As you can see I want both of them to work. Thank you

Comment: refer https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

Comment: You can certainly add multiple styles - what error is your react outputting from your code?

Comment: yeah I saw this before posting, but I didn't get a clear idea on implementing the above problem.. anyways thank you for your help

Comment: @ChrisCousins it is not showing any errors, the declaration which is given at last is working not the ones before that..

Comment: Oh I see, you should only supply one object to the style prop and in it you can have multiple style key value pairs - you’re sending two separate style objects.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @ChrisCousins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still you can optimize code like this, so that your render method looks neat.

Create variable of style JSON object.

```
const customStyle = {
  color: this.props.todo.done ? "#e6e6e6" : "#4d4d4d",
  textDecoration: this.props.todo.done ? "#e6e6e6 line-through" : "none"
};
```

Pass `customStyle` object as props to style element.

```
<div className="col-md-9">
   <span style={customStyle}>{this.props.todo.value}</span>
</div>;
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely I will give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

try this, i just removed redundant curly drackets

```
<div className="col-md-9">
       <span style={
                     {
                       color:this.props.todo.done ?'#e6e6e6' : '#4d4d4d',
                       textDecoration: this.props.todo.done ? '#e6e6e6 line-through' : 'none'
                     }
                }
       >
           {this.props.todo.value}
       </span>
</div>
```